# Coin in City Problem

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Please consider this problem.

in one city common coin is 1dollar ,2dollar  and 3dollar  coin. how many way of paying the The price for an 20dollar candy which the seller has no money and number of 1dollar  coins greater than number of 2dollar coins.

it's so nice. would you pleas help me in calculating?

Comment: yes i think it's 21 but i couldent satisfy myself for solution

Comment: If you show what you did, it will make it easier to see whether you have an error, and, if so, what it might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you require more $1'$s than $2'$s, you can think of each $2$ as coming with a $1$.  That makes another form of $3$. It will turn out that you need at least two more $1$'s because $20$ is not divisible by $3$. Now you can choose the number of $3$'s from $0$to $6$, then add enough $1$'s to make the total of $20$.  For each number of $3$'s, you can have $0$ to all of them real $3$'s and the rest be $2+1$.  If there are$6$ $3$'s, you have $7$ choices for how many will be real.  Similarly, if there are $5$ $3$'s, you have $6$ choices, so there are $7+6+5+\dots+1=28$

Comment: @Ross Millikan, Hi; what about solutions like 4 threes, 2 twos, and 4 ones? That is why I am getting 28 by direct count.

Comment: @bobbym:  yes, a fencepost error.  the $6$ can come from anything from $0+6$ to $6+0$.  Fixed and I agree with $28$

Comment: $x+2y+3z=20; x-y=a, y+z=b, a+3b=20$; so $b \in {0,...6}$ and when $b=k$ I have $k+1$ possibility for z and so I completely define $x$ and $y$; so I have $1+2+..+7=(7*8)/2=28$ possibility

Comment: @user153695:  is this clearer?  Yes, it is $28$